# view pdf in android using program or javascript

Tags: android

I'm new to android development. I have a link in HTML page which is having a PDF document URL as h ref, while clicking the link i need to open the PDF in adobe reader. if any one knows how to do guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class OpenPdf extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OpenPdfButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File file = new File("/sdcard/example.pdf");

            if (file.exists()) {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(OpenPdf.this, 
                        "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Hope this helps.